# Are there 2 non isomorphic graphs with the same Laplacian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, laplacian, graph-isomorphism

I am trying to form a symmetric Laplacian matrix from an ordinary directed graph but would I be able to form an isomorphism? My gut feeling says it is not injective. Are there any theorems on this.

I am seeing if there are 2 non isomorphic graphs with the same Laplacian matrix

Comment: What do you mean by "an isomorphism"? A graph isomorphism is a map from one graph to another graph. Here, we have a graph and a matrix.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am seeing if there are 2 non isomorphic graphs that give the same Laplacian matrix

Comment: If the symmetric Laplacian is generated in the way described by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Symmetric_Laplacian_for_a_directed_graph), the answer is clearly “yes”. Given any non-symmetric adjacency matrix $A$, its graph is non-isomorphic to the directed graph with the symmetrised adjacency matrix $S$ obtained from $A$. However, the two graphs have the same symmetric Laplacian, because their symmetric Laplacian matrices are generated from the same symmetrised adjacency matrix $S$.

Comment: @user1551 do you have a concrete counterexample?

Comment: I have already given one above.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not for undirected simple graphs. For the standard Laplacian the off-diagonal elements are identical to corresponding adjacency matrix elements multiplied with -1. The diagonal of the adjacency is zero.

Hence the Laplacian matrix uniquely specifies the adjacaency.

Graphs with the same same Laplacian matrix hence have the same adjacency matrix and are thus isomorphic.